# Grammar basic tense

Tags: grammar

A rule of present perfect tense says not to use adverb of time in the tense. then doesn't the rule makes the following sentence incorrect?

> I have known her for a long time.

Comment: Even worse, there's nothing wrong with *"I have seen her recently."* (Although you shouldn't say *"I have seen her an hour ago."*) Whoever told you that  *"rule"* needs to explain it much better.

Comment: First, there is no present perfect tense in English. There is a present tense and a perfect construction. Second, the rule you cite is false, as should be expected from a textbook that is this mistaken about tenses. Sentences are not made incorrect by an incorrect textbook rule; rather, the rule and the textbook should be discarded in the face of better evidence.

Comment: I have to close the question as self-contradictory nonsense. Obviously there is no such rule. Obviously you yourself have just supplied proof that there is no such rule. "A rule of English says not to use the letter G after the letter O. Then doesn't the rule make the word 'dog' incorrect?" Like, are you for real, mate?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the Present Perfect Continuous is a better choice to be opted out in the sentences involving: how long, since, and for; but there are some words in English that seem bizarre in their "-ing" outfit or the continuous form. A few examples are as follows.

```
**Like, love, hate, want, need, prefer, know, realize, suppose, mean, understand, believe, remember, belong, contain, depend, seem, see etc.**
```

It is suggested that we used the perfect construction of the present tense.
A few examples would make the things more limpid.

1. *How long **have you known** Albert? ( not ' have been knowing')*
2. *I **haven't seen** John since Monday.*
3. *I **have loved** you all my life.*

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't understand the use of "opted out" and "outfit" in your example. Can you please explain how you're using those terms?